# Minimizing weighted sum of matrix while ensuring distribution of outcomes in R

Tags: r, matrix, optimization

I am struggeling with an optimization problem involving a simple matrix operation. The task is the following: I have a sqare **matrix D** containing "damage multipliers" stemming from a prodcuction reduction in producing countries (columns) and felt by "receiving" countries (rows).

```
     AUT  BEL  BGR    CYP  CZE  DEU  DNK  ESP  EST  FIN  FRA  GBR  GRC  HRV  HUN  IRL  ITA  LTU  LUX  LVA  MLT  NLD  POL   PRT   ROU  SVK  SVN  SWE
AUT 1.48 0.15 0.18   0.08 0.19 0.22 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.02 0.05 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.14 0.00 0.02 0.03 0.02 0.02 0.00 0.04 0.10  0.09  0.11 0.16 0.17 0.11
BEL 0.03 2.70 0.34   0.09 0.05 0.03 0.02 0.01 0.04 0.09 0.09 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.08 0.02 0.00 0.04 0.03  0.37  0.09 0.07 0.15 0.29
BGR 0.01 0.02 9.81   0.09 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.06 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.02  0.12 0.01 0.00 0.01
CYP 0.00 0.01 0.01   9.87 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.04 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
CZE 0.19 0.11 0.08   0.07 4.14 0.27 0.01 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.03 0.05 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.02 0.32  0.07  0.03 2.57 0.05 0.05
DEU 0.29 2.54 0.27   0.15 0.19 1.71 0.10 0.04 0.06 0.22 0.22 0.09 0.03 0.02 0.11 0.03 0.08 0.12 0.08 0.07 0.00 0.28 0.28  0.55  0.25 0.26 0.11 1.09
DNK 0.01 0.09 0.02   0.09 0.01 0.14 3.43 0.00 0.02 0.12 0.02 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.01 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.00 0.01 0.03  0.05  0.01 0.01 0.01 1.39
ESP 0.02 0.26 0.06   0.05 0.02 0.03 0.02 2.72 0.45 0.04 0.22 0.05 0.04 0.01 0.01 0.05 0.06 0.02 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.02 0.03  1.28  0.05 0.02 0.01 0.32
EST 0.00 0.01 0.00   0.03 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 5.03 0.17 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.00 0.04 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05
FIN 0.01 0.09 0.02   0.03 0.01 0.01 0.06 0.00 0.21 5.48 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.00 0.01 0.02  0.05  0.01 0.01 0.00 1.99
FRA 0.04 0.89 0.11   0.13 0.03 0.08 0.03 0.18 0.04 0.08 5.19 0.05 0.02 0.01 0.03 0.05 0.06 0.06 0.03 0.03 0.00 0.14 0.04  0.54  0.08 0.04 0.03 0.79
GBR 0.03 0.80 0.09   2.13 0.03 0.05 0.12 0.08 0.03 0.30 0.15 3.13 0.02 0.01 0.02 0.41 0.02 0.12 0.02 0.05 0.00 0.19 0.06  0.36  0.05 0.04 0.02 2.28
GRC 0.00 0.04 0.14   0.26 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 2.10 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.03  0.03 0.00 0.00 0.02
HRV 0.19 0.01 0.01   0.03 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 2.25 0.03 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.01  0.01 0.00 0.09 0.01
HUN 0.29 0.07 0.08   0.17 0.30 0.08 0.02 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.06 0.00 0.00 0.01 4.83 0.00 0.01 0.09 0.01 0.05 0.00 0.01 0.05  0.04  0.13 0.23 0.06 0.04
IRL 0.00 0.03 0.01   0.06 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.03 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.80 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01  0.02  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.03
ITA 0.76 0.46 0.40   0.20 0.06 0.24 0.02 0.18 0.04 0.05 0.19 0.03 0.14 0.06 0.06 0.06 4.16 0.05 0.02 0.07 0.00 0.14 0.05  0.37  0.15 0.08 0.21 0.34
LTU 0.00 0.02 0.01   0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.03 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 2.18 0.00 0.03 0.00 0.00 0.01  0.01  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02
LUX 0.00 0.14 0.00   0.02 0.00 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 4.04 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.01  0.00 0.00 0.01 0.01
LVA 0.00 0.01 0.00   0.03 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.05 0.15 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.16 0.00 6.77 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.01  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.03
MLT 0.00 0.00 0.00   0.09 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.67 0.00 0.00  0.00  0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01
NLD 0.02 0.86 0.07   0.08 0.02 0.04 0.03 0.01 0.03 0.11 0.08 0.03 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.05 0.01 0.07 0.03 0.02 0.00 2.03 0.03  0.23  0.04 0.03 0.02 0.43
POL 0.02 0.09 0.03   0.19 0.16 0.13 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.06 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.00 0.01 0.33 0.00 0.03 0.00 0.01 2.18  0.05  0.02 0.11 0.01 0.11
PRT 0.00 0.05 0.01   0.10 0.00 0.03 0.01 0.07 0.02 0.01 0.04 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  2.53  0.01 0.00 0.00 0.07
ROU 0.04 0.06 0.89   0.13 0.04 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.31 0.00 0.02 0.02 0.00 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.03  0.04 10.52 0.06 0.01 0.03
SVK 0.23 0.04 0.02   0.08 1.12 0.60 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.01 0.32 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.11 0.00 0.00 0.07 0.00 0.02 0.00 0.00 0.34  0.03  0.03 7.06 0.02 0.03
SVN 0.13 0.01 0.02   0.01 0.01 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.02 0.01 0.00 0.05 0.01 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00  0.01  0.01 0.01 6.77 0.01
SWE 0.02 0.20 0.05   0.08 0.02 0.03 0.26 0.01 0.12 0.90 0.04 0.03 0.00 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.01 0.06 0.00 0.02 0.05  0.12  0.03 0.02 0.02 8.05
```

The values represent the effect of a unitary shock in production: ie. if country AUT reduces production by one unit, the damage felt in country DEU is 0.29. Hence, the matrix can be seen as a symmetric network of production effects between countries.

My goal is to find the optimal weights of a weighted unitary shock (i.e. weighting the columns so that the total reduction of production summed over all countries is = 1) that:

- ensure a certain distribution of damage across receiving (row) countries (i.e. the row sums), lets say an equal distribution
- while at the same minimizing the damage in the overall economic system

I've tried solving it as a simple non-linear optimization problem with equality constraints, using the package Rsolnp:

```
# objective function to be minimized (global damage)
damage <- function(weights) {
  D_weighted <- t(t(D)*weights); return(sum(D_weighted))
}

# constraints (combined in one function:
constr <- function(weights) {
  # constraint 1: sum of weights needs to be 1
  c1 = sum(weights)
  # constraint 2: equal distribution in damage outcome
  D_weighted <- t(t(D)*weights)
  damage_per_country <- rowSums(D_weighted)/sum(D_weighted)
  c2 = damage_per_country/sum(D_weighted)

  return(c(c1, c2))
}

# target distribution of damage outcome (for example: equal distribution)
targ_dist <- c(rep(1/(ncol(D)), ncol(D)))

# starting weights (sart with same production reduction in every country)
startweights <- rep(1/ncol(D), ncol(D))

# run optimization with Rsolnp
opt_weights <- solnp(pars = startweights, fun = damage, eqfun = constr, eqB = c(1, targ_dist), LB = rep(0, ncol(D)), UB = rep(1, ncol(D)), control=list(outer.iter=1000,trace=0, tol= 0.001))
```

but it doesn't converge and returns a warning message:

"The linearized problem has no feasible solution.  The problem may not be feasible".

Changing the tolerance doesn't solve the problem. It might be that this solver is not suited for this kind of problem or I need to reformulate the problem completely. I'd be thankful for any help!

Comment: You may want to show code that we can run so we can reproduce this.

Comment: The code is all there, except for the construction of the D matrix. You can download the matrix file [here](https://www82.zippyshare.com/v/Neecv76J/file.html)